# Do different anvil materials have different capabilities?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Can my iron anvil make every possible object from any metal bar, or do I need a steel anvil for some things?

I thought I had seen a post mentioning an anvil made from steel to work the more difficult ores, but I may have been misreading it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anvil material has no effect on useability or product quality. Iron and Steel anvils are exactly the same, and behave identically to gem anvils (made from Strange Moods) in all instances.

The one advantage steel anvils have is that they can be requested by the dwarven trade delegation, meaning if you don't have access to steel in any other way, you can simply buy the steel from the dwarven caravan, and then melt it back down into useable bars.

Comment: So, you're saying my Adamantite anvil is a waste? I should melt it down to be used for building other things?

Comment: @theJollySin It's not a waste per se, but it's not any better than an iron anvil.

Comment: Note you can't use a non-magma-safe anvil in a Magma Forge. But the chances of this happening are rare.